# Facebook Instant Games and Unity SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-instant-games

I use the Facebook SDK unity for authorization on the Facebook. Then I send the access token to the server to identify the user. But if I use authorization in the Facebook Instant Games, then the error falls:

> Blocked opening '<url>' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set

. (I don’t need this window).
I could use the HTML code, but I can't get the access token that way.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to get an access token on Facebook Instant Games.